Can a region of electromagnetic waves alone be considered a thermodynamic system? Can work and heat interactions be made sense for them?
Consider an ideal antenna producing coherent radio waves, and suppose the waves are not received by any body (they are sent off to space). Can we say a work interaction/transfer has been done? Or is this just nonsensical? Or... is this actually a heat interaction/transfer?
I mean, something happened, so I would say it is an interaction, and assuming the antenna was ideal, no heat was really produced (or at least we can say most energy did not go into heat production but instead into EM wave production). However, EM waves are not really a material body so it might lie outside of what classical thermodynamics was meant to analyze.
I am very curious what (hopefully informed) people think.
(To clarify, by linearity we know different EM waves can't interact with one another, so considering two systems of EM waves is trivial. My question about whether work or heat interactions can be made sense of for interactions between a material body and EM waves.)

This is not an antenna, but you may be interested in the “Ultraviolet Catastrophe” and the “Rayleigh Jeans” formula

The thermal noise of a resistor (Nyquist-Johnson noise), a form of black body radiation that has temperature and entropy, can be filtered, amplified, frequency converted, etc., and be transmitted by an antenna, and it can also be received, just as well, most famously as the cosmic microwave background. Since most antennas are made of metal$^*$, and unless it is a superconductor it also has some resistance itself producing Nyquist noise at the ambient temperature along with anything else it would transmit/receive. This is all thermal phenomena in the sense of any other thermal phenomena and is routinely part of any sensitive satellite or radio astronomy receiver design.
A coherent radiation, on the other hand, is a form of of thermodynamic work.

$^*$some antennas are made of dielectrics but they also produce Nyquist noise by parasitic dissipation

I love this answer. To be extra clear, 1. We can indeed treat a region of EM waves as a thermo system using classical thermo,  right? 2. A radio transmitter must produce some coherence or else we couldn't use it to communicate, so can I say that there is both work and heat transfers? (heat for thermal noise and work for the coherent part of the wave) Thanks.

(1) yes, the black body radiation in a volume $V$ has internal energy density $u=aT^4$, has entropy density $\tfrac{4}{3}aT^3$, and pressure $p=\tfrac{u}{3}$, and satisfies the Gibbs equation: $dU=TdS-pdV$ for $S=sV;U=uV.$

(2) it is possible to communicate with noise but it needs some coherence. For example, take a fixed temperature noise source and modulate its nominal average amplitude level, ie., its temperature. This actually was done until spread spectrum was invented; it may still be found in electronic warfare applications to confuse the radar/comms receivers background, ie., reference, setting.

(3) yes, it is thermodynamic for it involves both work and entropy transfer. Even the "single" frequency oscillator whose unmodulated signal is transmitted carries with it the temperature of its resonator/amplifier mostly in the form of phase noise and some of it as amplitude noise. The phase/amplitude noise is thermal, and the rest of it is the work.

EM field in general does not easily conform to the standard idea of system in thermodynamics, because EM field often permeates matter walls, spreads to infinity, also carries energy to infinity, and can't be easily contained and does not have few macroscopic parameters that can be manipulated.
In a specific situation where the EM field is contained in finite space region, e.g. if the EM field is in a reflective box with a piston by which we can change the volume, then we can apply thermodynamics to this box (and this is how the density of energy of radiation at given temperature can be derived).

Hmm. I honestly admit my own question is definitely frustrating to think about (even to myself). At first, I realized that in my own thought-experiment the region through which EM waves pass is an open system, but then I realized EM waves don't even have mass. Thank you for pointing out the difficulties.

Anyways, the second part of my question was, to the extent that we can make sense of whatever I'm thinking about, can we talk about "producing EM waves via work" vs "producing EM waves via heat?" Or is this nonsense?

Yes we can talk like that, when the process has clear macroscopic force and displacement analog (work of voltage source on current in antenna), or not controlled (heating by thermal radiation). In general, there are also processes which are kind of in between work and heat, like transfer of energy via friction - it's work because there is force and displacement, but also we often treat it as heat since in frame of the body, the energy gained behaves as injected heat.
